# How does early voltage affect collector current?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

The transistor in the following circuit is said to feature \$I_{C} = 1.0mA\$ at \$V_{BE} = 0.7V\$ and \$V_{CE} = 10V\$. If \$V_{A} = 50V\$ and \$\beta = 50\$, find \$V_{B}\$ and \$V_{C}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRtYhy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Attempt:

\$V_{B}\$ Calculation:

\$V_{B} = 10 - 0.7 - 196.5I_{B}\$

\$I_{B} = \frac {I_{C}} {\beta} \$

\$V_{B} = 10 - 0.7 - 196.5 *\frac {1mA} {50}\ = 5.3V\$

\$V_{C}\$ Calculation:

\$V_{C} = 10 - 1 = 9 V\$

How do I incorporate the early voltage 
\$V_{A}\$ into the calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early effect (base-width modulation) means that \$I_C\$ current will change his value as \$V_{CE}\$ change, even if \$V_{BE}\$ and \$(I_B)\$ is kept constant.

So we have another source of a nonlinearity.

For your example circuit we have:

\$\beta = 50\$,\$V_{CC} = 10V\$,\$R_C=1k\Omega\$,\$R_B=196.5k\Omega\$; and the Early Voltage is \$V_a=50\$

Without Early effect the DC operation point is:

$$I_B=\frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE}}{R_B} = \frac{10V - 0.7V}{196.5k\Omega} = 47.328\mu A $$

And \$V_B = V_{BE}\$

Hence the collector current (without Early effect) is equal to:

\$I_{CO} =\beta*I_B = 47.328\mu A * 50 = 2.366mA\$

and the \$V_{CEO}=V_C\$ voltage (without Early effect).

\$V_{CEO} = V_{CC} - I_{CO}*R_C = 10V - 2.366mA*1k\Omega = 7.6335V\$.

But if we include Early effect \$I_C\$ current will change.

We have

$$I_C = I_{CO}*(1 +\frac{V_{CE}}{V_a}) $$

$$V_{CE} = V_{CC} - I_{C}*R_C$$

And if we solve this for \$I_C\$ current we will end up with this:

$$\large I_C =\frac{I_{CO}(V_a+V_{CC})}{I_{CO}R_C + V_a} = I_{CO}\frac{1+\frac{V_{CC}}{V_a}}{1+\frac{R_C}{R_O}}$$

$$I_C =  2.366mA\frac{1+\frac{10V}{50V}}{1+\frac{1k\Omega}{21.129k\Omega}} = 2.36641mA * 1.14577 = 2.71137mA $$

where \$R_O = \frac{V_a}{I_{CO}} = \frac{50V}{2.36641mA} = 21.129k\Omega \$

All this mean that Early effect can be model as a resistor \$R_O\$ connected from the collector to the emitter of an “perfect” transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWmziP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, I deliberately skip the fact that the \$V_{BE}\$ value was given for \$I_C=1mA\$. And here we have \$I_C > 1mA\$ so the\$V_{BE}\$ value will also be slightly larger than \$0.7V\$.

Comment: So which formula applies for collector current in linear region: this one $$I_C = I_{CO}*(1 +\frac{V_{CE}}{V_a}) $$  or this one $$\large I_C =\frac{I_{CO}(V_a+V_{CC})}{I
_{CO}R_C + V_a} = I_{CO}\frac{1+\frac{V_{CC}}{V_a}}{1+\frac{R_C}{R_O}}$$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't Ico be replaced with Ic? Like this:  \$R_O = \frac{V_a}{I_{C}} \$

Comment: @Keno Ico is a collector current without Early effect (perfect transistor). So if you want to find the Ic current and includes the Early effect. We can use this equation Ic = Ico*(1+Vce/Va) (1) but you do not know Vce, hence we need additional equation for Vce. Vce = Vcc-Ic*Rc (2), and we substitute (2) into (1) and solve for Ic we get this: Ic = (Ico* (Va + Vcc))/(Ico* Rc + Va) = Ico * (1 + Vcc/Va)/(1 + Rc/Ro) .

Comment: Also I want to point out that we (almost) never in real life include Early effect when we are try to compute the DC operating point.

Comment: Why not? If we include Early Voltage in multistage transistor circuit I am sure that the results can be significantly different from the ideal ones, right?

Comment: Oh by the way, if you put numbers into this equation Ic = (Ico (Va + Vcc))/(Ico* Rc + Va) = Ico * (1 + Vcc/Va)/(1 + Rc/Ro) first equation does not equal second one.

Comment: @Keno You need to check your math again. As for the Early Voltage. We sometimes include the Early effect in AC analysis but never in DC.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. One more thing: If we consider Early Voltage, is Vce any different from the Vce from graph where we don't consider Early Voltage (If Vbe is constant)? Probably it is, since Ic is larger than Ico, then Vce is also smaller than Vceo, right?

Comment: @Keno Yes, you're right.

Comment: I would only like to ask about gm (transconductance) in BJTs. Some equations for Rin and Rout are using gm. I saw a few times that gm= Ic/Vt (where Vt is thermal voltage). Is this correct?

Comment: @Keno For the bipolar transistor gm (transconductance)  is the slope of the collector current to the base-emitter (slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) function). gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe) = Ic/Vt = Ic/26mV = 40*Ic, But also gm = Ic/Vt = beta/rbe. We also have anther point view (from T-model). We include transresistance re = d(Vbe)/d(Ie) is a dynamic (differential) emitter resistance (often called "little re") re = Vt/Ie and we sometimes use this approximation \$r_e = \frac{Vt}{Ie}\approx \frac{Vt}{Ic} \approx \frac{1}{gm} \$ but the exact value is gm = beta/((beta +1)*re)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267662/how-to-derive-the-ac-emitter-resistance-of-transistor-amplifier-biasing/267668#267668

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen a IV plot for a bipolar

[image]

What is the Early voltage for this transistor? Consider that very top line:
intercepting the left axis(0 volts) at 4mA, and intercepts the 10_volt line at 7.5mA. [ some very clean numbers, used by the artist ]
Our deltas are 7.5mA - 4mA = 2.5mA; 10v - 0v = 10v.

Now extend that to the left, from 0v/4ma point. The intercept with Zero current is 10v * 4mA/2.5mA = 10v * 1.6 = 16 volts to the left. Ve = 16 volts

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv0egN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>