# why does this approach neglect the output resistance of the bjt in calculating gain?

Tags: bjt, resistance, gain

[image: see question 3]

This is the question that I would like to ask about. My question is with regards to finding Vc for question 3. This is the memo for the question:
[image: memo for the question 3]

However, I have a problem with regard to how they find Vc. Surely, if Vc is equal to Vcc- Rc(ic) then that is regarding the circuit as DC and ignoring the effect of the output resistance of the bjt, in which case it would be equal to Vcc- Rc|| Ro *ic? 
Ro would be equal to Va/ic = 80/1.5*10^-3 = 53kohm
Or do you think that for question 3, without stating it, that it was assumed that Va = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must distinguish between DC analysis and small-signal (AC signal only 10mV peak).

When we are doing DC analysis we usually treat the BJT as a current controlled current source with fix Vbe value and beta.  And sometimes, we are a force to use a Schottky equation to find the DC operating point. But almost always we ignore the Early effect in DC calculation. And the model we used to model the Early effect is also a linear model.

See the example here 
[How does early voltage affect collector current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299672/how-does-early-voltage-affect-collector-current/299693#299693)

But even this is just another simplification of a reality.

On the other hand in the small-signal analysis, we are using the highly linearized BJT's small-signal model. So we can use linear equations and theory. Because do not forget that in real life the is BJT highly nonlinear device and this is why we using linearized models. Because the reality is too complicated for us.

Answer (score 0):

> Surely, if Vc is equal to Vcc- Rc(ic) then that is regarding the
>   circuit as DC and ignoring the effect of the output resistance of the
>   bjt

It's simple ohms law; if a current \$I_C\$ flows through \$R_C\$ then the volt drop it creates subtracts from \$V_{CC}\$ to give you \$V_C\$. You can only regard the output resistance of the collector being effectively in parallel with \$R_C\$ when doing an AC small signal analysis.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is this. When I consider the output resistance of the bjt in the small signal equivalent and calculate the gain from looking at that, then the output voltage is equal to -vpi*gm*(Rc||Ro) and input is vpi, resulting in a gain of -gm(Rc||Ro) - this is -214.66. However if we were to just do an ohm's law, it would just have the Rc and no Ro. In the small signal analysis, if I were to ignore Ro, and make the gain equal to -Rc*gm this results in the same gain of 231 as in the memo. So my question is, why is it ok to ignore the output resistance albeit using the ohm's law?

Comment: Let me clarify : the Vc that is calculated using the small signal analysis (a different approach) is different to that of using the ohm's law. If small signal theory is used for ac analysis, then 1. why is it ok to use ohm's law calculations for ac?

Comment: AC analysis should use the two resistors in parallel. For DC analysis you already have decided upon Ic and that value of Ic is what it is despite Ro. The collector acts (in these sorts of simple analyses) as a constant current defined by the base current and gm.

Comment: Usually Ro >> Rc so in the analysis it is usually omitted

Comment: That makes sense. I guess the difference isn't that much.