# How to calculate small signal parameter for a BJT when Early voltage is taken into consideration?

Tags: bjt, small-signal

I have proved one formula of

**output impedance 
ro = (Va+Vce)/Ic = Va/Ic'**

where **Ic is collector current** and **Ic' is collector current neglecting early effect**.

But reading from standard texts other formulas are diverging like for
**gm{trans-conductance} = Ic/Vt**

**is formula given** in Razavi, Neamen .

But **I am getting**

**gm=β/rb = Ic'/Vt**

where rb is base emitter resistance and β is common emitter current gain.

Am I doing some mistake or its rather approximation the books are taking and in later case plz comment if the approximation is rather universally valid.

Comment: The Early effect can be modeled in the small signal equivalent circuit as a resistance between collector and emitter. See: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/bjts-after-biasing-the-small-signal-model/  Scroll down to "Accounting for the Early Effect" You're trying to make *gm* include the Early effect, that's over complicating things. It is much easier to leave *gm* alone and add a resistor to represent the Early effect. As we're dealing with a small signal model, that can be done.

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299672/how-does-early-voltage-affect-collector-current/299693#299693 But for a small signal purpose analysis we simply use this \$r_o = \frac{V_A}{I_C}\$

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie rb=Vt/Ibq by dynamic resistance of diode in base emitter junction in eber-molls model and   current through dependent current source is βIbq so transconductance = β/rb which is Ic'/Vt where Ic' is current through dependent current source on collector side and not current flowing in collector terminal so where I am wrong

Comment: Instead of concentrating on all the formulas, **draw the small signal model** with and without Early effect. Represent the Early effect as a **resistor** between emitter and collector. You simply **cannot** include the early effect into the controlled current source for Ic. So **forget** about the formulas for a moment and **THINK** what the Early does to the small signal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Model those like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBFuJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>