# Base current in a npn transistor in view of its small signal model

Tags: transistors, common-emitter, small-signal

[image]

We know that in a forward biased transistor we have βIb = Ic. 
However in the model it's clear that the above equality doesn't hold, we now have Ic > β.Ib.
What's wrong in my understanding of the model. 
Any help is appreciated 
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that the ib*beta does not hold anymore?

Comment: Because the current via collector is( βIb + the current via resistor )>Ic.

Comment: But r_o represents the early effect https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299672/how-does-early-voltage-affect-collector-current/299693#299693  So where is the problem?

Comment: I thought that βIb =Ic holds everywhere.

Comment: Try this example \$\beta = 100 , r_\pi = 2.5k \Omega , r_o = 2.5k \Omega, R_C = 2.5k\Omega\$ and we have \$v_{in} = 10mV\$  we now can find the output voltage this way:

 $$v_{out} = -\beta i_B \times R_C||r_o = 100\cdot4\mu A \times 2.5k\Omega||2.5k\Omega  =0.4mA \times 1.25k\Omega = -0.5V$$ thus the voltage gain is $$A_V = -\frac{\beta R_C||r_o}{r_\pi} $$ and \$i_{RC} = \beta i_B \times  \frac{r_o}{R_C + r_o} = 0.2mA \$ AS you can see we can still use \$\beta i_B \$

Answer (score 1):

> *we now have Ic > β.Ib*

and

> *small signal model*

Only if you allow the collector to emitter signal voltage to be non-zero.

Comment: Thank you, so is this model incorrect if you allow the collector to emitter signal voltage to be non-zero?

Comment: All BJT and MOSFET models are approximations. The model is better with \$r_o\$ than without it but, it's still an approximation. \$r_o\$ models the slope of the constant current of the active region. As a fixed value it doesn't account for early effect but it's better to have it than not to have it in your model.

Comment: "As a fixed value it doesn't account for early effect..."   however according to my understanding Ro accounts for the early effect indeed it's existence is to add an additional current which comes into existence due to early effect.

Comment: @YasirSadiq - did you mean to ask me something?

Comment: Yes, please see the comment above your, I've edited it.

Comment: Early effect changes the value of \$r_o\$. Early effect isn't modeled by \$r_o\$ being a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks, you said " ro models the slope of the constant current of the active region..."    the slope is due to early effect. So Ro has a link with early effect.    Also according to Wikipedia"The Early effect can be accounted for in small-signal circuit models (such as the hybrid-pi model) as a resistor" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect

Comment: @YasirSadiq look at the formula for that resistor - it depends on collector current hence, as collector current changes (or Vce changes) then \$r_o\$ changes. A fixed value for \$r_o\$ DOES NOT model early effect.

Comment: Anyhow, I see you've asked 3 questions now (and have sufficient reputation numerically) so might I take this opportunity to let you know that you that you can up-vote answers that are helpful and, when you get a good answer that you are happy with, you can formally accept that answer. It's best mentioned early on so that you don't get a reputation of being stingy (because people will stop helping you).

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation it needs 15 I've got 11. However i truly respect your time and effort. I Thank you for your time and effort dear :)

Answer (score 1):

In the small signal model you're looking at **change** in collector current (the transistor is biased such that the DC collector current is Ic).

Call the change ic(t) wrt the input voltage (or current in this case) ib(t).

Ignoring the Early voltage resistance R0, the small signal collector current

ic(t)= \$\beta\$ib(t) = gm vb(t) where gm= Ic/Vt and re = \$\beta\$/gm

Comment: Thank you ,   we are taking into account the early voltage thats the reason we have added Ro to the model. But if we do so then Ic > β.Ib.

Comment: If you short the output then ic(t) = β*ib(t). When you allow the collector voltage to change you'll get less ic. β here is not necessarily the same as the large signal β, sometimes it's called β_0 to distinguish it.

Comment: If we don't short the output that is take into account Ro then ic(t) = β*ib(t) doesn't hold.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't hold.